# Lengthen tick marks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, themes

Simple question I am trying to lengthen the tick marks in ggplot2 on the axis - how?

```
plot <- plot + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size =2))
```

If increase the size it only seems to increase the width of them, not the length?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `axis.ticks.length`, i.e.

```
plot + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(1, "cm"))
```